# Installing Deis in AWS without ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, f5-big-ip

I'd like to install a Deis cluster in AWS but without using ELB, since we have already paid for an alternative (BigIP), and our network guys are comfortable with it.

Is it easy to configure Deis not to use ELB, and rely on BigIP instead?

Answer (score 0):

If your network guys are comfortable with Big-IP then definitely investigate it as it will offer more features should they need features in addition to basic load balancing services.

If you're using Deis, you have a couple ways to configure and use Big-IP but definitely take advantage of it's REST API so you can automate your deployments.  You can either define new BIG-IP instances for each "platform" you plan on automating or you can use it as a monolithic entrypoint into your application infrastructure and only automate deployment and configuration of virtual IPs.  It'll depend on your application segregation requirements, but the platform will do either.

I myself, use a pair of BIG-IP's and use iControlREST (F5's API) to spin up and down the various virtual IP's and assign certs and traffic policies as needed for my testing environments.

Here's the link to F5's [iControlREST API](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iControlREST.HomePage.ashx) if you want to investigate that route.